# is there a way to get the original machine info of a file transferred by ftp

Tags: ftp

I am working on AIX,and there are some excuteable files on it, I know they are complied somewhere outside my working machine and then transferred by ftp to my working machine.Now I want to know the IP address  they original complied on, is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Read it from server log?

Comment: @Flash Thunder ,yeah,your answer seems right, but I never know there are server log of ftp.....I will google it

Comment: @Flash Thunder I have no the root right on AIX, can I check the server log?

Comment: That's off-topic for Stack Overflow.